# How to create procedure where you can choose which attributes to use

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure

For example I'll create this procedure

```
Create procedure MyProc (name varchar2:='', married varchar2:='', surname varchar2:='') IS
...
...
...
END;
```

And now I want sometime use it like this

```
MyProc (name=>'George', married=>'NO');
```

and sometime I need to use it like this

```
MyProc (name=>'Warren', surname=>'Palas');
```

and sometime I need to use it like this...

```
MyProc (name=>'Joey', married=>'YES', surname=>'BigJoey');
```

How can I obtain this status? Thanks for every advice

Comment: I'd stay away from (storing) `'YES'` and `'NO'` as 'boolean' values, and use (character) `'1'` (true) and `'0'` (false) instead.  Then in your stored proc, use the actual `BOOLEAN` datatype (which can't be stored...).

Answer (score 0):

Specifying your procedure as follows and invoking with the "=>" method as you have already done should achieve this.

```
PROCEDURE MyProc (name IN yourtable.name%type, 
married IN yourtable.married%type := NULL,
surname IN yourtable.surname%type := NULL)
```

By defaulting the parameters in the specification it makes the parameters "optional parameters".
A parameter with no default is known as a required parameter.

You can also specify your procedure inside a package and overload it.
Overloading a procedure means creating multiple procedures with the same name in the same package. How the procedure is called determines which of the procedures *actually* gets executed.

Deciding which way to go can depend on the degree of dissimilarity between the processing required for each of the types of call. generally overloading is good practice for code abstraction, structuring and maintenance purposes.